# Why multiply a sparse matrix(0.5) with a dense vector is slower than the normal multiply?

Tags: matlab

I generated a matrix with sparsity 0.5, and I want to know its speed multiplying a dense vector compared to the multiplying in the normal way.

```
function sparseTest()
    A = sprand(1000, 1000, 0.5);
    test(A);
    test(full(A));
end
function test(A)
    tic;
    b = rand(size(A, 2), 1);
    for i = 1:10000
        c = A * b;
    end
    toc;
end
```

The result is

```
Elapsed time is 10.968797 seconds.
Elapsed time is 10.194440 seconds.
```

what confuses me is that since there is only half non-zero numbers, I think the sparse multiplying should somehow be faster.

Comment: If you want to test the multiplication you definately should not include the matrix creation in the timing part.

Comment: I think I didn't.@DennisJaheruddin

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No. That is simply NOT a sparse matrix. You misunderstand when sparse matrices are useful. Those of us who do use them heavily would say that a matrix is not really sparse unless it has a density of less than 1%. Even that density is not very sparse!

A sparse matrix has extra bookkeeping when you use it, because now MATLAB essentially needs to worry about where the non-zeros are. So if you make a matrix that is essentially a dense matrix, and pretend that it is sparse, you are defeating the value of the tool.

Lets make a comparison or two. First, a completely dense matrix. I'll use Steve Eddins timeit tool from the file exchange. This does a very good job of estimating time taken, and does not require an explicit loop.

```
A = rand(1000);
As = sparse(A);
b = rand(1000,1);

whos A As
  Name         Size                 Bytes  Class     Attributes
  A         1000x1000             8000000  double              
  As        1000x1000            16008008  double    sparse
```

See that the fully dense matrix takes up considerably less space than the sparse form.

```
timeit(@() A*b)
ans =
   0.00039474

timeit(@() As*b)
ans =
    0.0023663
```

The overhead of the sparse matrix in a simple multiply is way too large.

```
As = sprand(1000,1000,.5);
A = full(As);
b = rand(1000,1);

whos A As
Name         Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes
  A         1000x1000            8000000  double              
  As        1000x1000            6303448  double    sparse
```

Here the two matrices barely show a size reduction for the sparse version. So calling it sparse is a waste of time in terms of space consumed. As well, as you found, the time consumed for multiplies is still not a gain.

```
timeit(@() A*b)
ans =
   0.00027594

timeit(@() As*b)
ans =
    0.0005011
```

However, what happens when the matrix is closer to what I suggested in terms of sparsity?

```
As = sprand(1000,1000,.01);
A = full(As);
b = rand(1000,1);

whos A As
  Name         Size                Bytes  Class     Attributes

  A         1000x1000            8000000  double              
  As        1000x1000             167176  double    sparse   

timeit(@() A*b)
ans =
   0.00023629

timeit(@() As*b)
ans =
   5.3167e-05
```

Ok, so this now is saving some serious space. And some serious time too.

But really, the time for a multiply is NOT why we use sparse matrices. It is the time required to solve a linear system of equations that makes us use sparse matrices. This can be a MASSIVE savings, where the problem will be essentially unsolvable using full matrices. A common problem for me might involve a 40000x40000 matrix, with perhaps a density of 0.02%. I would spend days waiting for the full version to finish, but only seconds for a sparse solve in that case.

For example, consider gridfit, a function of mine that is on the file exchange. It creates surfaces from scattered data. In this example, the tool will need to solve a linear system of equations with 40000 unknowns.

```
timeit(@() gridfit(rand(100,1),rand(100,1),rand(100,1),linspace(0,1,200),linspace(0,1,200)))
ans =
      0.83624
```

So for everything, including setting up that system of equations, it took less than 1 second.

The (in this case, non-square) linear system that it solves is VERY sparse.

```
whos A
  Name          Size                 Bytes  Class     Attributes
  A         80100x40000            4126408  double    sparse
```

How sparse is it?

```
nnz(A)
ans =
      237900

nnz(A)/40000
ans =
       5.9475
```

So on average, only 5.9475 non-zeros per row, with 40000 columns. And we don't have the time it would take for me to do a full linear solve with that system. At least I don't have any desire to try it.

Comment: Thanks for correcting me passionately. Indeed a sparse matrix is not cast to full when you multiply it. Perhaps I was confused by what happens when you add a 'normal' scalar like 0 to a sparse matrix.

Comment: Thanks very much for your testing! But what I really want to know is the underlying implementation reason, instead of how to use the tool. Since I only need to do 50% multiplication, I expect to see it runs a little faster.

Comment: @cloudyFan - my guess is the simple full matrix multiply uses the blas to pump sequential elements in memory through a pipeline as fast as possible. A sparse multiply must pull elements from essentially random positions in memory, so taking more time. The point is you cannot get that flat out speed. Just wanting magic to happen is not enough. Sparse won't help you here, because your matrix is insufficiently sparse for a gain to occur.